# Create multiple delete functionality for all the attachments related to a particular case

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, visualforce-component, bulk-delete

I have created a button on case detail page called "delete attachments" once pressing that, the page directs to below VF page where all related attachments to that particular case are displayed with checkbox.

When I select the attachments using checkbox and press delete button on my VF page that particular attachment must get deleted from case.Similarly there must be an checkbox at top column of select, upon selecting that check box all attachments must get selected.

Issue i'm facing is upon selecting checkbox and I press delete, they aren't getting deleted.I was suggested to use wrapper class but that didn't work as well.

VF Page

```
    <apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="DelAttachments_Img_Controller" >
<apex:form >
<apex:sectionHeader title="Select the Attachments you want to Delete: " description="You can delete more than one attachments from the list below"/>
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton Value="Delete" action="{!AddAttachments}" />
        <apex:commandButton Value="Cancel" action="{!GoBack_toRequest}" immediate="true" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstAllAtach}" var="atch" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Select">
            <apex:inputCheckbox immediate="true" value="{!atch.toAdd}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!atch.at_name}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Image Preview" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Type" value="{!atch.at_type}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Size" value="{!atch.at_size}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Date Created" >
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date, MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}" >
                <apex:param value="{!atch.at_createDate}" />
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller

```
    public class DelAttachments_Img_Controller {
public Id CaseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CaseID');
public Case ourCase {get; set;}
public List<String> lstSelectedAtach {get; set;}
public allAttachments[] lstAllAtach {get; set;}
Public  List<selectedAttachments> searchResult {get;set;}
Public Map<Id,selectedAttachments> SelectedResultMap {get;set;}
public List<Id> selectedAtchIds {get; set;}
public Boolean addAttachments {get; set;}



public DelAttachments_Img_Controller (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    if (CaseId != null) 
        ourCase = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Contact.Name, Thread_Id__c FROM Case WHERE Id =: CaseId LIMIT 1];
    lstAllAtach = new list<allAttachments>();
    List<Attachment> relatedAttachments = [SELECT Id, Name, ContentType, BodyLength, CreatedDate FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId =: ourCase.Id];
    if(!relatedAttachments.isEmpty() && relatedAttachments != null) {
        for (Attachment a : relatedAttachments) {
            allAttachments oneAtch = new allAttachments();
            oneAtch.toAdd = false;
            oneAtch.at_id = a.Id;
            oneAtch.at_name = a.Name;
            oneAtch.at_type = a.ContentType;
            oneAtch.at_createDate = a.CreatedDate + offset;
            oneAtch.at_size = (((Decimal)a.BodyLength)/1024 >=1024.0)? (((Decimal)a.BodyLength)/1024).setScale(2)+' MB' : (((Decimal)a.BodyLength)/1024).setScale(2)+' KB';
            lstAllAtach.add(oneAtch);
        }
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/DelAttachments_Img');
        pageRef.setRedirect(false);
        //return pageRef;
    } else {
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'No Attachments available!'));
        //return null;
    }
}


public PageReference AddAttachments() { // adds the selected attachments to the list to delete them
    List<Attachment> lstAttToDelete = new List<Attachment>();
    for(allAttachments wAtt: lstAllAtach) 
    {
        if(wAtt.selected  == true)
        {
            lstAttToDelete.add(wAtt.attachobj);
        }
    }

    if(lstAttToDelete.size() > 0 )
    {
        Delete lstAttToDelete;
    }

    PageReference pageref = new PageReference('/apex/DelAttachments_Img');
    pageref.setRedirect(false);
    return pageref; 
}

PageReference DeleteAttachments() {
    selectedAtchIds = new List<Id>();
    lstSelectedAtach = new List<String>();
    for (allAttachments a: lstAllAtach) {

    }

    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/DelAttachments_Img');
    pageRef.setRedirect(false);
    return pageRef;
}


public PageReference GoBack_toRequest() { // navigates the user back to the Request detail page
    PageReference pageref = new PageReference('/'+CaseID);
    pageref.setRedirect(true);
    return pageref;
}

public Double offset {
    get {
        TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
        return tz.getOffset(DateTime.now()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24.0);
    }   
}

//Public class selected

public class selectedAttachments { // holds the names of attachments that have been selected to be attached
    public Id AtchId {get; set;}
    public String AtchName {get; set;}
    // Public Attachment attachobj{get; set;}
    Public Boolean Selected {get;set;}
}

public Class allAttachments { // holds info of each attachment to display
    public Boolean toAdd {get; set;}
    public Id at_id {get; set;}
    public String at_name {get; set;}
    public String at_type {get; set;}
    public String at_size {get; set;}
    public DateTime at_createDate {get; set;}
    Public Boolean Selected {get;set;}
    Public Attachment attachobj{get; set;}

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside the naming of the fields and methods, which is a bit odd, I think you are over-complicating it a bit...

You could use the standard controller to fetch the attachments, so you don't need to query them manually in the controller. You could use the "IsDeleted" checkbox to mark the ones you want to delete and then take care of it in the controller.

My VF proposal

```xml
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="DelAttachments_Img_Controller">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Select the Attachments you want to Delete: " description="You can delete more than one attachments from the list below"/>

        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton Value="Delete" action="{!doDelete}" rendered="{!hasAttachments}" />
                <apex:commandButton Value="Cancel" immediate="true" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Case.view, '5002500000C0oqp')}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Case.Attachments}" var="attachment" rendered="{!hasAttachments}" >
                <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!attachment.IsDeleted}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!attachment.Name}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Image Preview" />
                <apex:column value="{!attachment.ContentType}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Attachment.fields.BodyLength.label}">
                    {!
                        IF(
                            attachment.BodyLength<1024,
                            TEXT(attachment.BodyLength) + ' B',
                            IF(
                                attachment.BodyLength<(1024*1024),
                                TEXT(ROUND(attachment.BodyLength/1024,1)) + ' KB',
                                TEXT(ROUND(attachment.BodyLength/(1024*1024),1)) + ' MB'
                            )
                        )
                    }
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!attachment.CreatedDate}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

            <apex:pageMessage severity="info" strength="2" summary="No attachments available!" rendered="{!!hasAttachments}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

My Controller Proposal

```java
public class DelAttachments_Img_Controller {

    public Case myCase {get;set;}

    public DelAttachments_Img_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.myCase = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public Boolean getHasAttachments() {
        return !myCase.attachments.isEmpty();
    }

    public PageReference doDelete() {
        List<Attachment> recordsToDelete = new List<Attachment>();

        for(Attachment forAtt : myCase.Attachments) {
            if (forAtt.isDeleted) {
                recordsToDelete.add(forAtt);
            }
        }

        if (!recordsToDelete.isEmpty()) {
            delete recordsToDelete;
        }

        PageReference pageref = Page.DelAttachments_Img;
        pageref.getParameters().put('id', myCase.Id);
        pageref.setRedirect(true);
        return pageref; 
    }
}
```